# Error Compiling Moses. No dist folder or moses.ini file

Tags: macos, compilation, compiler-errors, machine-translation, moses

I'm a beginner programmer, so I'm still trying to get a hold of things. Please be gentle.

I'm trying to install and compile Moses (http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Development.GetStarted) on OS X but I'm running into quite a few problems.

I've been following the instructions from this site (http://www.statmt.org/moses_steps.html) and all goes well until I actually compile Moses. I'm using the following code:

```
./bjam -a toolset=clang -d5 --with-srilm=/Users/user/tools/srilm-1.7.1 --with-giza=/Users/user/bin -j2
```

This is supposed to create several files in dist/bin/, including the moses.ini decoder itself. However, the dist/bin/ folders aren't showing up at all. I don't see any errors while Moses is in the process of compiling--all seems to go well until I actually check the files and try to run Moses.

When I try to run a test, I use the following:

```
/Users/user/moses/dist/bin/moses -f moses.ini < in > out
```

And I receive the error: No such file or directory.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? Any and all advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is a plethora of answers for compiling moses on osx in the moses mailing list. Most propose to create a virtual machine with a linux distribution (e.g. ubuntu) and install moses there.

There are also ready-made virtual machines (with older distributions, though) in the following link:
http://www.statmt.org/moses/RELEASE-3.0/vm/ .